# Exposing local types in Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, scope, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to expose the return type of a function where the return type is defined within the function's own scope.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/** @return {MyType} */
function func(){
  /** @constructor */
  function MyType(){}

  return new MyType();
}

/** @type {MyType} */
var instance = func();
```

When I compile this [here](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), I get two type errors one for the `@return` annotation and one for the `@type` annotation. Both errors say `Unknown type MyType`. Is there a way to get this pattern to compile with type-checking?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't find the type because `MyType` as a type is not available when you create `instance` (can't do new MyType() or instance instanceof MyType).

This can be fixed by adding a typedef in the same scope as instance or create instance in the same scope as MyType.

Both:

```
/** @typedef {Object} */
var MyType;
/** @return {MyType} Returns new MyType **/
function func(){
  /** @constructor */
  function MyType(){
  }
  return new MyType();
}
/** @type {MyType} */
var instance = func();
```

and:

```
function func(){
  /** @constructor */
  function MyType(){
  }
  /** @type {MyType} */
  var instance = new MyType();
  return new MyType();
}
```

Won't produce any warning

**[update]**

To provide a complex type through annotation is going to be painfully hard. You can make the type as complex as you want. Using externs would not work because externs variables and their functions won't be renamed to shorter names (without some extra compile parameters) and you can't re define the type. So I guess you're basically stuck with providing a typedef annotation:

```
/** @typedef {{hands:number,doSomething:function(string):boolean}} */
var MyType;
/** @return {MyType} Returns new MyType **/
function func(){
  /** @constructor */
  function MyType(){
   this.hands=22;
  }
  MyType.prototype.doSomething=function(msg){
    return true;
  }
  return new MyType();
}
/** @type {MyType} */
var instance = func();
/** @type string */
var myString=instance.hands;//warning:found number required string
/** @type Array */
var myArray=instance.doSomething("hi");//found boolean required Array

instance.doSomething(22);//found number required string
instance.doSomething();//at leas 1 argument(s)
```

Comment: Hi HMR, I believe that is the correct reason as to why it can't find the type. The first solution looks close to what I'm after, but it accepts any type that is an instance of Object from the function and I was hoping to find a way to make it only accept instanceof MyType. (IE. `function func(){ return {}; }` compiles without error, but I want it to have a type checking error)

Comment: I know that in that outer scope I can't do something at runtime like `instance instanceof MyType` because `MyType` doesn't exist in that scope. But I was hoping that it could be sorted out at compile time.

Comment: @Paulpro My guess is that when JS can't find the type when you use it then the compiler can't either but I don't know for sure how the compiler does it. I've updated my answer and think you're stuck with using a `type` annotation to define it. It can be as complex as you want but would be nice if you can spread it over multiple lines. Haven't found a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "MyType" is scoped with "func" and is not available outside.  You might do better to define an @interface in the global scope and just use that type outside the defining  function.